# Generate Network plot from large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graphviz

Suppose I have this dataframe `df` that contains 3794 rows x 2 columns, where column `a-number` represents nodes with directed edges to nodes in `b-number`:

```
            a_number    b_number
0       0123456789343   0123456789991
1       0123456789343   0123456789633
2       0123456789343   0123456789633
3       0123456789343   0123456789628
4       0123456789343   0123456789633
... ... ...
3789    0123456789697   0123456789916
3790    0123456789697   0123456789886
3791    0123456789697   0123456789572
3792    0123456789697   0123456789884
3793    0123456789697   0123456789125
3794 rows × 2 columns
```

Additional information:

```
len(df['a_number'].unique())
>>> 18

len(df['b_number'].unique())
>>>1145
```

I am trying to generate an image representation of the graph. Here's code to apply networkx:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()

for  i, (x, y) in df.iterrows():
    G.add_node(x)
    G.add_node(y)
    G.add_edge(x,y)
    
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True, font_size=14 , node_size=2000)
```

I get this output:

[image]

I am having some problems in visualizing the graphs created with python-networkx, I want to able to reduce clutter and regulate the distance between the nodes. Please advise. What can I do on the code? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First to reduce the clutter I would start by decreasing the node size, to maybe 200 or 400.

Try to reduce the font_size parameter in the draw function. This parameter regulate the size of the node's labels. Since you have large node names, it will help reduce the clutter.

If having the labels on the graph is not necessary, then remove them to make it cleaner by passing the with_labels=False to the draw function.

Then to regulate the distance between nodes you an use the spring layout for the nodes position.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.8)
nx.draw(G, pos , with_labels = True, font_size=7, node_size=400)
```

The k parameter in the spring  layout allows you to regulate distance between nodes. You can try different values to see what suit you most.